# Visitor Counter For dynamic pages

Tags: php, mysql, counter, visitor-pattern

I am using the following codes for my dynamic webpages which looks likes http://localhost/xxx/IND/xxxx/detail.php?v_id=VID1234567890.

When the visitor counter gets updated its updates all the ids

v_id          |   visits
VID1234567890 |   5
VID2234567890 |   5
VID3234567890 |   5

```
<?php
$counter='';//initilize counter
$sql="SELECT hit FROM venue";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$counter=$rows['hit'];

// if count is empty
if(empty($counter)){
$counter=1;
$insertCounter="INSERT INTO venue set hit='".$counter."'";
$result1=mysql_query($insertCounter);
}

echo "You are visitor num=>". $counter;

// increment visitor count
$increasecounter=$counter+1;
$sql2="update venue set hit='".$increasecounter."'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
?>
```

How can i show distinct visitor counter for different ids
v_id          |   visits
VID1234567890 |   10
VID2234567890 |   5
VID3234567890 |   15

Regards
Uttam

Comment: how are you keeping track of the ids while they visit?

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a simple table with vid  field

as v_id is input for you table

```
Insert into simple_table (vid) values ($v_id)
```

then list query

```
select vid, count(*) from simple_table group by vid;
```

above query will list as below

```
VID1234567890 , 10 
VID2234567890 , 5 
VID3234567890 , 15
```

Comment: hi chandran, thanks for revert. The exact problem is all V_IDs are connected to their respective information pages and this is where i have embedded the visitor counter (codes mentioned above). So when i visit the info page of a V_ID, the counter should increase the value by 1 of that particular V_ID. But it is not happening, instead it increase the visitor counter by 1 of all the V_IDs